# How do I avoid object expressions for functions that return a SAM interface

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

I am a kotlin newbie so maybe this is trivial but I failed to find any relevant help at kotlinlang.org.

In an effort to learn a bit about kotlin I like to implement `PushStream` library.

I wanted to define the fundamental types something like this:

```
typealias Receiver<T>   = (T) -> bool
typealias PushStream<T> = (Receiver<T>) -> Unit
```

AFAIK type-aliases isn't supported yet so above is just pseudocode.

So my first attempt was this:

```
interface Receiver<T> : (T) -> Boolean {
}

interface PushStream<T> : (Receiver<T>) -> Unit {
}

fun <T> singleton (v : T) : PushStream<T> {
    return { r : Receiver<T> -> r (v) }
}
```

kotlin then says:

```
Error:(10, 12) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is (Receiver<T>) -> Boolean but PushStream<T> was expected
```

I seem to be able to get around it with:

```
fun <T> singleton (v : T) : (Receiver<T>) -> Unit {
    return { r : Receiver<T> -> r (v) }
}
```

But that's not the signature I want especially for the more advanced operators I might need to specify the full function type:

```
fun <T> singleton (v : T) : ((T) -> Boolean) -> Unit {
    return { r : Receiver<T> -> r (v) }
}
```

This I believe makes the API harder to read.

What I could do is using an object expression:

```
fun <T> singleton (v : T) : PushStream<T> {
    return object : PushStream<T> {
        operator override fun invoke (r : Receiver<T>) : Unit {
            r (v)
        }
    }
}
```

This works but I would like to use Lambda expressions to keep the code more succinct.

Any tips welcome. Also if you know of any interesting blogs/presentations on programming with higher-order functions in kotlin that would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Kotlin made the choice to support implicit SAM interface conversion to functions only for Java interfaces. Not for Kotlin interfaces. I agree that this hurts readability in some cases. Type aliases will come in the next version (AFAIR). JetBrains will then see if that fixes the problem of if conversion of Kotlin interfaces should be allowed. There's a feature request for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770. In the meantime, I would just use `(T) -> Boolean` in the signatures. Hopefully refactoring the code with type aliases won't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no type aliases (yet), type signatures can not* substitute each other. In your case you need to use composition instead of inheritance to create a level of abstraction:

```
open class Receiver<T>(val op: (T) -> Boolean)

open class PushStream<T>(val op: (Receiver<T>) -> Unit)

fun <T> singleton (v: T): PushStream<T> {
    return PushStream<T> { r -> r.op(v) }
}
```

I replaced interfaces with classes because I don't see the rest of the code. If you need interfaces, then use factory functions:

```
interface Receiver<T> {
    val op: (T) -> Boolean
}

fun <T> receiver(op: (T) -> Boolean) = object : Receiver<T> {
    override val op = op
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the PushStream-Interface in java, you can use it like that:

```
fun <T> singleton (v : T) : PushStream<T> {
    return PushStream { r : Receiver<T> -> r (v) }
}
```